# The image in imageview is blurry (Android java)

Tags: java, android, imageview

while the imageview I put in the activity appears clear on the design screen, it appears clear on the emulator and the real phone. How can I fix this? the image is in the "drawable/xxhdpi" folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8iZX.png)